# Why does the `onload` event not fire on nested iframes with framebusting?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, framebusting

Consider the following three pages.

1. `Foo.html` is opened locally in the browser, and so has a URL with prefix `file:///`.
2. `Bar.html` is in the same directory has `Foo.html`.
3. `Bar2.html` lives in `/var/www` and I am running `Apache` on `localhost`.

**Foo.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  foo = function() {
    alert("frame changed");
  };
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <iframe width="200" height="300" src="Bar.html" id="my-iframe" onLoad="foo" /> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**Bar.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
  <iframe width="200" height="300" src="http://localhost/Bar2.html" id="my-iframe" /> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**Bar2.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  if (top.location != self.location){
      parent.location = self.location;
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button type="button" onclick="document.location.href='http://bing.com'">Hello World</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When `Foo.html` is loaded in Firefox, by running `firefox /path/to/Foo.html` on the command line, the frame busting code in `Bar2.html` breaks out of `Bar.html`. At this point, the user gets an alert `frame changed`.

When I click the button, the `iframe` changes (the button vanishes), but I do not get an alert.

**Why is the `onLoad` not firing the second time when the page changes?**

Answer (score 1):

The issue lays in the fact that when Bar2.html is being loaded by the iframe in Bar.html this condition is false

```
if (top.location != self.location)
```

As a result, when Bar.html is loading Bar2.html this is called

```
parent.location = self.location;
```

Which issues a redirect in the page and cancels the affect of the onload event since the page technically never finished loading.

Comment: Might be worth noting that this happens twice, taking it up a frame each time until `self === top`

Comment: @PaulS. - Are you sure it happens twice? I only noticed once (the second time the condition is true and as a result no redirect occurs).

Comment: `self == top` will not happen because of the same origin policy.

Comment: After the `iframe` under `Foo` gets redirected, is there any way to fire an event on the parent page `Foo` that can detect this redirection, since `onLoad` on the `iframe` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your script

```
  if (top.location != self.location){
      parent.location = self.location;
  }
```

will run on Bar2.htm and change the location of its parent (previously Bar.htm). Then the alert comes.
Then, the script will run in the parent (previously Bar.htm) but top.location is still not equal to self.location . (top.location is now equal to Foo.htm and self.location is equal to Bar.htm ) so when you click the button, the parent page has been redirected to Bar2.htm . Meaning the alert code and the iframe is gone.

Comment: The top-level parent `Foo.html` is still there. When the click happens, the iframe goes to Bing.com, but the `iframe` is still there.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see what's going on here. The onLoad event handler is going off once simply because the frame loaded, not redirected. But cross domain policy is preventing you from accessing "parent" (you need to use "top" for some reason) because localhost is being treated as a website whereas the other pages are being treated as on your hard drive, naturally.